# Angular ngFor iterating over more than one HTML item

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a very simple Object (which I build from a JSON) and I want to display it as a description list. I would like to have the view of my Angular component like this:

```
<dl>
   <dt> key1 </dt>
   <dd> value1 </dd>
   <dt> key2 </dt>
   <dd> value2 </dd>
   ...
</dl>
```

How can I have the ngFor directive repeating more than one HTML item?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`KeyValuePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe):

```
<dl>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of yourObject | keyvalue">
    <dt>{{item.key}}</dt>
    <dd>{{item.value}}</dd>
  </ng-container>
</dl>
```

Maybe it is also worth to check if `yourObject` exists with some use of [`NgIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else):

```
<dl *ngIf="yourObject; else noObject">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of yourObject | keyvalue">
    <dt>{{item.key}}</dt>
    <dd>{{item.value}}</dd>
  </ng-container>
</dl>
<ng-template #noObject>
  No object.
</ng-template>
```

Comment: what if my "item.value" is in turn an object? can I inspect the object using a pipe?

Comment: You can use a second `NgForOf`, again with a `KeyValuePipe`. Though, if you want just to display the raw object, maybe `<dd>{{item.value | json}}</dd>` or `<dd><pre>{{item.value | json}}</pre></dd>` works well.

Comment: I was expecting something easier, like 
<dd> {{item.value.attr1}} {{item.value.attr2}} </dd> 
but that doesn't seem to work, unless you define the corresponding interface...